# How can I watch a question in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I was wondering, is there a way to track particular questions in Stack Overflow?  For instance, if I see a question asked that I would like to see the answer to, is there a way that I can mark that question so that I can come back to it later?

Comment: See the star? Click it.

Comment: Making something a favorite vs watching are two different intended actions. I like to favorite questions that I can reference quickly but watch questions that I would just like to see what the answer is for a learning experience but not "keep around".

Comment: @Matthew Jones I actually don't see the star, unless you mean my browser's one that bookmarks the page, but I do see "Share Edit Follow Flag" under every question, and "Follow" I think will do the trick. I'm guessing Stack Exchange's interface has changed since 2009.

Answer (score 20):

There is a pretty useful StackApps app called StackStalker (Google Chrome Extension) written by [Jason Edleman](http://www.jasonedelman.com/) that does exactly this (Including notification badges).  You can check it out here:

[StackStalker: Be Notified When Your Question Is Updated (Chrome Extension)](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension)

Comment: This is the only answer which actually answers the question. Favoriting a question does not notify you of changes.

Comment: StackStalker seems to have it’s own DB. Would be great if some app picks up the question I “starred” already...

Comment: The extension seems to have some bad reviews. What is your experience on it?

Comment: @RobertSiemer is the DB stored locally or can you use it on any computer?

Comment: @jarno I can't remember using it myself.

Answer (score 16):

Each question has an RSS feed that you can subscribe to if you *need* to see everything that happens.

Otherwise, favouriting the question is a pretty good way to go.

Comment: I don't know how to subscribe to RSS for a single question.  See this to subscribe for ALL your favourite (starred) questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions  in short, something like this:  http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1/favorites?body=true  Thanks, George!

Comment: @SamWatkins There's an RSS link on the lower-right of each question page with the label "question feed".  It's of the format http://$HOST/feeds/question/$QUESTION_ID .

Comment: As stackoverflow won't email you changes, you may use some free service to email RSS changes to you when there is a new content.

Comment: Do you know working online RSS subscribing service that works with the sites? My Yahoo does not seem to work and Bloglines is down AFAIK. Those are the services shown in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

Put them in Favorites, click on the star under the votes of your question. Here is how you can watch them - In your profile page there is a Favorites tab, it lists all your favorite questions.

Comment: Guys, how can I edit my answer? I gave it in stackoverflow, now I can't edit it(My login is the same Yahoo ID). And what about the reputation from the two upvotes, it's not here, it's not in the stackoverflow...

Comment: Associate your accounts! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133579?tab=accounts#sort-top

Comment: Svetlozar is right, same answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71243/watch-list-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Click the star to the left of the question.

Comment: And subscribe to this (substitute your user number). http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1/favorites?body=true

Comment: Could not subscribe to that by searching it in Feedly.