# RSS feed for favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, feed, bookmarks

I feel like this is almost certainly a duplicate, but I couldn't find what it's a duplicate of.

Is there an RSS feed for updates (new answers, edits, comments, maybe even votes) on your "favorite" questions? If no, can we have one?

Answer (score 21):

This is now possible. I have written a small application called [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that does exactly that.

Here is how it works: given an API request, the app will convert it to an RSS feed. Since there happens to be an API method for retrieving a user's favorite questions, stack2rss can easily generate a feed for this.

An example that fetches Jeff Atwood's (user #1) favorite questions on StackOverflow:

> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1/favorites?body=true

Comment: What a brilliant thing, thanks! :) Please note somewhere that `stackoverflow` part can be replaced with something like `programmers.stackexchange` to access favs from that site.

Comment: Does this feed only include favorite questions, or answers comments and changes?  I do not see my comments.  We want to see the comments and answers!  Perhaps this is the reason for obscure downvote.  Your app is cool, but does it answer the question?

Comment: Any way you could add the username and time of the change like favorites page on the SO website does?  It's difficult to search through the whole question page to find what changed otherwise.  Even better if you could figure out how to scrape the actual change text rather than the question text--though I suspect that would be far more difficult.

Comment: oops the link stopped working for me getting an error `There was an error processing this page.The API response did not contain an array`. My  question is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253981/rss-feed-for-favorite-question-activity/253993?noredirect=1#comment20038_253993)

Comment: @Chandrayya: please see the header at the top of this question: http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source

Comment: As http://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-fully-open-source notes, the service isn't yet working with the new version of StackOverflow's API, but it's on github: https://github.com/nathan-osman/stack2rss

Comment: @alxndr: You can try it out here: http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com

Comment: quickmediasolutions site does not seem to work as well.

Answer (score 4):

I can see how (perhaps) individualized RSS feeds are a bit much.  Another solution to the problem is to have the same top-of-the-screen bar that notifies us of other activity can notify us of activity against our favorites.

Comment: There are already feeds for individual user activity and individual question activity, so it doesn't seem like there's any worry about having too many feeds. A user may want to favorite a question to be able to find it easily in the future, but not want to follow it very closely, so I would oppose a top-of-the-screen notification bar unless there was a user preference to disable it.