# How do I get notified about updates to my questions?

Tags: support, search, posting

it is a good idea to search before asking a question.

Let's say I want to know if I can be informed (not via email) that there is **anything new** happening in the question I posted or I added to my favourites. I tried to search for such question/info with no success.

Should I go **through all pages** in the search?

**How many** different searches should I perform?

**How** would you **search** for such info?

Comment: You mean you want to keep track of updates to questions?

Comment: yes, I renamed the question.. this has almost nothing to do with search IMO

Comment: @Jeff: Well, he wanted to ask first how to search for it, before actually asking the question me thinks.

Comment: yes, I wanted to know how to search before asking any question

Answer (score 4):

Well, I mostly search on google first. A well crafted google query will get you to an existing question most of the time:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+notify+question+favorite+update+-email

This gives a couple of results which might already answer your question:

> [RSS feed for favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/rss-feed-for-favorite-questions)
>   [Make recent activity and responses show new comments on questions/answers I have commented on (even if I don’t own them)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have)
>   ...

Comment: @fretje: thanks,it didn't come to me to use google to search stackoverflow.com. I will test rss and hopefully accept your answer

Comment: I thought that there MUST be some internal feature that would easily led me to the new answer/comment hopefully in real time. Let's see how rss works