# How to watch a post?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I watch a question in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13988/how-can-i-watch-a-question-in-stack-overflow)

Is there an ability to watch a post that you wish to see the answers to at a later point, but cannot contribute?

(Other than adding to browser favourites?)

I have tried searching for an answer to this with no luck sadly.

Comment: Now the question is, how do I lock this post?

Comment: You don't. StackOverflow is a wiki like site, anyone can change it. You can _ask_ the moderators to lock a post.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/86239

Answer (score 2):

Mark the question as favourite - click the star to the left of the question, just under the upvote/downvote buttons.

It will now feature in the favourites list in your profile page, including any updates to it.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the star. The question is then one of your favorites. You can check your favorite questions later in your profile.